# Does DB2 OS/390 BLOB support .docx file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, db2, docx

ASP.net app inserts Microsoft Windows 2007 .docx file into a row on DB2 OS/390 Blob table.  A different VB.net app gets the DB2 OS/390 Blob data.  VB.net app kicks off Microsoft Word to open the .docx file but then Microsoft Word pops up a message that the data is corrupted.  Word will allow you to fix the data so the file can be viewed but it is extra steps and users complain.

I've seen some examples where .docx can be converted to .doc but they only talk about stripping out the text.  Some of our .docx have pictures in them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide some code?  What construct are you using to insert/select?

Answer (score 3):

I see that this question is 10 months old. I hope it's not too late to be helpful.

Neither DB2 nor any other database that allows a "Blob" data type would know that the data came from a .docx file, or do anything that would cause Word to complain. The data is supposed to be an exact copy of whatever data you pass to it.

Similarly, the Word document does not "know" that it has been copied to a BLOB object and then back.

Therefore, the problem is almost certainly with your handling of the BLOB data, in one or both of your programs.

Please run your first program to copy the .docx file into the databse, then run the second one to read it back out. Then use a byte-by-byte tool to compare the two files. One way to do this would be to open a command window and type:

```
fc/b Doc1.docx Doc2.docx
```

If you have access to some better compare tools, by all means use them... but make sure that it looks at EVERY BYTE, not just the printable characters.

Obviously, you ***ARE*** going to find differences, or else Microsoft Word wouldn't give you errors on the second one when the first one is just fine. Once you see what the differences are, hopefully you will understand what is going wrong and how to fix them.

I had a similar problem several years ago (I was storing graphics, but it's the same basic problem). It turns out that the document size was being affected - I would store 8005 bytes into the BLOB object, and when I read it back out I was getting 8192 bytes. NUL (0) bytes were being appended to the end of the data.

My solution at the time was to append an "X" to the end of the BLOB data when I wrote it to the database. Then, when I read it back, I would search for the very last "X" in the data and remove it, along with any data after it. That way, I could recover the original data. What I should have done was store the data length in the database along with the BLOB data. Then you could truncate the file to that size, eliminating the corruption.

If appended NUL bytes aren't your problem, then you'll need to do something else to fix the problem. But you don't have a clue until you know what changed. Something did.